# How can I get audio files from iPod Music Library (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift

I try to get file list from the Music Library (iPod Music Library), but I can't do it, my list is always empty. I sure that I have tracks in Music Library, I check it in other app - and it works. But as I remember that application sent me a request to access the Music Library. Perhaps I also need to create such a request? Help me solve the problem. I use this code to get file list:

```
func fetchFileList() {
     let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songs().items
     let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems ?? [])
     print("mediaCollectionItems: \(mediaCollection.items)") //It's always empty
     //Then I'd like to get url of the track
     //let item = mediaCollection.items[0]
     //let pathURL = item.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? URL
     //print("pathURL: \(pathURL)")
}
```

[image: Music Library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the Music Library, you have to add `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist with a description about what you want to do with the music.

Se apple documentation for more info: [MediaPlayer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer)